# PyMongo [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, ssl, mongodb-atlas, pymongo-3.x

I'm using Python 3.9.5 and PyMongo 3.11.4. The version of my MongoDB database is 4.4.6. I'm using Windows 8.1

I'm learning MongoDB and I have a cluster set up in Atlas that I connect to. Whenever I try to insert a document into a collection, a `ServerSelectionTimeoutError` is raised, and inside its parentheses there are several `[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate`.

[Troubleshooting TLS Errors](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/tls.html#troubleshooting-tls-errors) in the PyMongo docs weren't too much help as they only provided tips for Linux and macOS users.

It's worth mentioning that if I set `tlsAllowInvalidCertificates=True` when initializing my `MongoClient`, everything works fine. That sounds insecure, and while I am working on a small project, I would still like to develop good habits and not override any security measures in place, so I'm hoping there is an alternative to that.

From all the searching I've done, I'm guessing that I'm missing certain certificates, or that Python can't find them. I've looked into the `certifi` package, but [this](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/tls.html#dependencies) part of the docs makes it seem that should only be necessary if I'm using Python 2.x, which I'm not.

So yeah, I'm kind of stuck right now.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Well, I eventually decided to install `certifi` and it worked.

`client = MongoClient(CONNECTION_STRING, tlsCAFile=certifi.where())`

Wish the docs were a bit clearer on this, but maybe I just didn't look hard enough.

Comment: Helped with PyMongo & Mongoengine Connect

Comment: Can confirm, this works with Atlas.

Comment: I don't understand why this is not in the docs

Answer (score 13):

In Flask server I solved by using:

```
import certifi

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MONGO_URI'] = 
'mongodb+srv://NAME:<PWD><DBNAME>.9xxxx.mongodb.net/<db>? retryWrites=true&w=majority' 
mongo = PyMongo(app,tlsCAFile=certifi.where())
collection_name = mongo.db.collection_name
```

Answer (score 4):

By default, pymongo relies on the operating system’s root certificates.
You need to install `certifi`:

```
pip install certifi
```

It could be that Atlas itself updated its certificates or it could be that something on your OS changed. “certificate verify failed” often occurs because OpenSSL does not have access to the system’s root certificates or the certificates are out of date. For how to troubleshoot see TLS/SSL and PyMongo — PyMongo 3.12.0 documentation 107.

So try:

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient(connection, tlsCAFile=certifi.where())
```

Answer (score 3):

I saw an answer that worked for me, it appears i had not yet installed the python certificates on my mac, so from the following path i went and installed it

```
/Applications/Python 3.10/Install Certificates.command
```

Only change the version of your python, after that everything, worked fine for me

PS: I had been trying to solve the problem for half a day, I even asked ChatGPT

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Step 1:

```
pip install certifi
```

Step 2:

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient(connection, tlsCAFile=certifi.where())
```

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
ssl=true&ssl_cert_reqs=CERT_NONE
```

after db name of  your url string works fine

```
"mongodb+srv://username:Password@cluster0-gbdot.mongodb.net/DbName?**ssl=true&ssl_cert_reqs=CERT_NONE**&retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens in django as well just add the above code to your `settings.py` in Django:

```
DATABASE = {
'default': {
'ENGINE': 'djongo',
 "CLIENT": {
           "name": <your_database_name>,
           "host": <your_connection_string>,
           "username": <your_database_username>,
           "password": <your_database_password>,
           "authMechanism": "SCRAM-SHA-1",
        },
    }
}
```

But in host you may get this issue:

> "pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError:"[SSL:
> CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get
> local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)

So for this you can add:

```
"mongodb+srv://sampleUser:samplePassword@cluster0-gbdot.mongodb.net/sampleDB??ssl=true&ssl_cert_reqs=CERT_NONE&retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```