# Connect MongoDB to Python

Tags: python, mongodb

I try to connect to MongoDB database from https://cloud.mongodb.com/

My code:

```
import pymongo
from pymongo.server_api import ServerApi

client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://<My-Username:<My-Password@test.umh3xqu.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority", server_api=ServerApi('1'))

print(client.list_database_names())`
```

Errors:
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: ac-gyw4foz-shard-00-01.umh3xqu.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992),ac-gyw4foz-shard-00-00.umh3xqu.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992),ac-gyw4foz-shard-00-02.umh3xqu.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]

How to fix???

List all databases

Comment: The connection is failing with `CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED`. Do you understand what that error message is telling you?

Comment: yes, i try using &tlsAllowInvalidCertificates=true but still don't work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyMongo \[SSL: CERTIFICATE\_VERIFY\_FAILED\] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68123923/pymongo-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certificate-verify-failed-unable-to-ge)